# PyQt5 Layouts not moving button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

while working with PyQt5 i tried to put buttons on a Layout, but it dont seem to workfor some reason? The button simply doesent move vertically, to the other side :D

Heres the code:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt, QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys


class Window(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("WebScraper")  # setting title
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 400)   # setting geometry

        self.UiComponents()  # calling method
        self.show()  # showing all the widgets



    def UiComponents(self):

        self.SearchButton = Qt.QPushButton("Search", self)
        self.SearchButton.resize(150, 80)

        self.VBox = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        self.VBox.addStretch()
        self.VBox.addWidget(self.SearchButton)
        self.setLayout(self.VBox)

        self.showMaximized()  # Showing window as maximized.


App = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)


window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: explain yourself better, your question is not clear. Please do not put unnecessary information

Comment: @eyllanesc, sorry for the unclearity, but i hope the edited answer is better?

Comment: 1) Recommendation: run your script from the CMD on console to get the warning: *QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on Window "", which already has a layout*, 2) remove `self.setLayout(self.VBox)` and add `central_widget = Qt.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        central_widget.setLayout(self.VBox)`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks! Helped alot, but why am i doing this?